# Simple DBLayer class review

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a simple DBLayer class. But I am not sure whether this class have any bug/issue using in production.

```
public class DBLayer
{
    private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

    public static DataTable GetDataTable(string strSQL, CommandType type)
    {
        var objCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
        objCmd.CommandType = type;
        return GetDataTable(objCmd);
    }

    public static DataTable GetDataTable(SqlCommand objCmd)
    {
        SqlConnection objConn = null;
        try
        {
            objConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            objCmd.Connection = objConn;
            var objAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objCmd);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            objAdapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }
        finally
        {
            objConn.Close();
        }
    }

    public static int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand objCmd)
    {
        int r = -1;
        SqlConnection objConn = null;
        try
        {
            objConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            objCmd.Connection = objConn;
            objConn.Open();
            r = objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            objConn.Close();
        }

        return r;
    }
}
```

Please review this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good. You may also want some other things like `getScalar` (A single object, or string, as in 1 cell), `getDataRow`, just the top row, `getDataRowCollection`, i frequently only use datatable to get the rows, and forget about the columns, so I can iterate over it like so....

```
DataRowCollection drc = getDataRowCollection("SELECT * FROM tblTest");
for(DataRow r in drc){
    Console.WriteLine(r["name"]);
}
```

So you could have `NonQuery`, you may want to test these before using them....

```
    public DataTable getDataTable(SqlCommand objCmd)
    {
        SqlConnection objConn = null;
        try
        {
            objConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            objCmd.Connection = objConn;
            var objAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objCmd);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            objAdapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }
        finally
        {
            objConn.Close();
        }
    }

    public DataRowCollection getDataRowCollection(SqlCommand objCmd)
    {
        return getDataTable(objCmd).Rows;
    }

    public DataRow getDataRow(SqlCommand objCmd){
        return getDataRowCollection(objCmd)[0];
    }

    public string getScalar(SqlCommand objCmd)
    {
        SqlConnection objConn = null;
        try
        {
            objConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            objCmd.Connection = objConn;
            return objCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            objConn.Close();
        }
    }

    public int NonQuery(SqlCommand objCmd)
    {
        SqlConnection objConn = null;
        try
        {
            objConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            objCmd.Connection = objConn;
            return objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            objConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

I would recommend writing quite a few variations of the methods, and implement enums for each connection string so you don't mis-type anywhere and have them set in concrete.

Take a look at my `getScalar` variations....

```
    public static string getScalar(string query)
    {
        return getScalar(query, defaultConnection);
    }

    public static string getScalar(string query, ConnectionString cs)
    {
        return getScalar(query, new { }, cs);
    }

    public static string getScalar(string query, object param, ConnectionString cs)
    {
        return getScalar(query, param, cs, defaultTimeout);
    }
    public static string Query(string query, object param, int to)
    {
        return getScalar(query, param, defaultConnection, to);
    }

    public static string getScalar(string query, object param, ConnectionString cs, int to)
    {
        return getScalar(ConnectionStringToDb(cs), query, param, to);
    }

    public static string getScalar(MySqlConnection db, string query)
    {
        return getScalar(db, query, defaultTimeout);
    }

    public static string getScalar(MySqlConnection db, string query, int to)
    {
        return getScalar(db, query, null, to);
    }

    public static string getScalar(MySqlConnection db, string query, object param, int to)
    {
        string result = "";
        if (db.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            OpenConnection(db);
        MySqlParameter[] p = ObjectToParameters(param);
        using (db)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
                command.Connection = db;
                command.CommandText = query;
                command.CommandTimeout = to;
                foreach (MySqlParameter pm in p)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(pm);
                }
                result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Also if you class works as expected it should be fine... Looks okay. I use mine day to day, but I use MySql so I'm not to sure on the differences between the two classes, should be relatively the same.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in the code:

- do use `using` statement to dispose connections and other disposable objects
- static methods won't allow you to use unit-testing on your business logic.
- don't use `obj` prefixes or non-descriptive names like `r`

As a result of original code refactoring I got the following:

```
public interface IDBLayer
{
    DataTable GetDataTable(SqlCommand command);
    int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand command);
}

public static class DBLayerExtensions
{
    public static DataTable GetDataTable(this IDBLayer dbLayer, string sql, CommandType type)
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql))
        {
            command.CommandType = type;
            return dbLayer.GetDataTable(command);
        }
    }
}

public class DBLayer : IDBLayer
{
    private static readonly string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

    public DataTable GetDataTable(SqlCommand command)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            var result = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand command)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your approach. But the problem is that in the project static methods invocation are spoiled all over places. So, I can't make it instance. However, I will use using clause. Thanks.